# Limit user memory usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory

I'm using SQL Server 2014. There are some users who can query the tables. The problem is, that most of the time these queries use a lot of memory. I want to know if there is any way to limit resources per user?

There is not a specific query. I just want to control users. Sometimes they do crazy things.

Comment: Why would you care that the queries do use memory? This very much sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). If you have other problems that you suspect are caused by lack of RAM, please explain the reasoning with more details.

Comment: Yes there is a way but did you not tried finding out why certain query is requesting more memory grant/given more memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated before, you can use Resource Governer to limit memory usage for specific users.

To summarize shortly the steps you should do:

1. Create a resource pool. This example has max 30% of memory, be careful with that.

   ```
   CREATE RESOURCE POOL UserMemoryPool
   WITH
   ( MIN_MEMORY_PERCENT=0,
   MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT=30)
   GO
   ```
2. Create a workload group which will use resource pool.

   ```
   CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP UserMemoryGroup
   USING UserMemoryPool;
   GO
   ```
3. You should define a Classifier function to tell SQL Server who is gonna be in this group.

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UserClassifier() 
   RETURNS SYSNAME WITH SCHEMABINDING
   AS
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @Workload AS SYSNAME
       IF(SUSER_NAME() = 'UserNameToLimit')/*Specify the user*/
           SET @Workload = 'UserMemoryGroup'
       ELSE
           SET @Workload = 'default'
       RETURN @Workload
   END
   GO
   ```
4. Lastly to enable Resource Governor

   ```
   USE master
   GO
   ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = dbo.UserClassifier);
   GO
   ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
   ```

You can find additional info at [Resource Governor at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx)

Comment: I personally think it is bad advice to just turn on the resource governor to limit resource for a given user. You could be introducing factors that impact all other users/tasks/statements running on the server. Limiting a user to a set of given resources is also limiting the availability of these resources for others. E.g.: If a statement runs for 1000 ms on 8 processors in parallel because of MAX_DOP = 0 and you suddenly limit the user's query to one processor, then you could be at 8000 ms runtime. Other limiting factors will limit other resources for others (tasks/schedulers/threads/workers)

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/resource-governor-enabled/

Comment: Well, you made your point very clear and i totally agree with you on crazy queries should be analyzed and tuned. But nearly every feature of SQL server has a trade-off. Traces, online index rebuild etc has some disadvantages but it is what it is. Resource governor is the way to limit user resource, not the solution bad queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you don't give users the ability to run "ad hoc" queries in a productive environment.

Your statement ...

> Sometimes they do crazy things.

... implies that they probably do **not** know what they are doing. Turning on the Resource Governor in a productive environment could have a negative impact on the production.

[Blitz Result: Resource Governor Enabled](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/resource-governor-enabled/)

If you have to enable the Resource Governor please ensure you read the documentation and understand the implications and impacts this can have.

[Resource Governor (2012)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=sql.120).aspx) (Microsoft MSDN)

The easiest way is to restrict their ability to log in to the server.